# Update ListBox collection immediately afted save

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have MainWindow and user control AddEditData. Both using it's own viewmodel representation
MainWindowViewModel and AddEditViewModel.

On left side I have listbox with list of data items and on right side AddEditView which display data details selected on listbox. On AddEdit I have button save which saves data from textboxes.

Under the hood everything works, data is properly saved inside database but change on data details is not visible immediatly, change is visible on next app. execution.

I know about INotifyPropertyChanged and I implemented on my listbox data collection in the first place. Here's the code

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public ObservableCollection<Book> Books
{
    get { return books; }
    set {
          books = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Books");
        }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
 <ListBox Name="listBoxData" 
          DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelDataSource}}" 
          ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BookTemplate}"                              
          ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

On AddEditViewModel I added command to save button which saves data to the db and using Mediator pattern send message to the MainWindow to inform that data is saved.

```
 Repository.Save(book);
 Mediator.NotifyColleagues("SaveData", book);
```

Again, how to update listbox item immediatly after save action?

Update
I've added UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged

```
 <ListBox Name="listBoxData" 
              DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelDataSource}}" 
              ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BookTemplate}"                              
              ItemsSource="{Binding Books, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

but this nothing changes, listbox remains the same after saving data.

Comment: How the `AddEditViewModel` is initialized, if on save, you modify the initial `Book` object and the `Book` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`  the changes should be visible immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the properties of the `ListBoxItem` to update when the fields in the `AddEditData` control are edited, then you'll also need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the class of the items inside the `Books` collection.

If you want them to update only after a save, then you'll need to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` to all of your `Binding`s in the `AddEditData` control and manually update them after a save... that's a bit of a pain because you'll need to access each `Binding` in turn to update the values:

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = 
    someTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
```

Alternatively, if you add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to all of your `Binding`s, then the fields in the items will update as soon as they are edited.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I've updated question. Please check. I've updated listbox with updatesourcetrigger but problem remains.

Comment: And did you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: Books collection has OnPropertyChanged("Books"); Do I need to implement on Book domain class as well?

Comment: Well, as the first line of my answer says, you'll need to do that *if you want the properties of the `ListBoxItem` to update when the fields in the `AddEditData` control are edited*.